# Boot GRUB to entry not booted to last time?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I'm not sure I'd actually do this, but is there a way to make GRUB automatically select the boot option I didn't use last boot?
i. e. If I booted into Windows last boot, it selects Ubuntu. If I booted into Ubuntu, it selects Windows.
I was just wondering because I often find myself rebooting to switch OSes, as I have different games that I run on each (though with my new rig I don't need to run stuff on Ubuntu just for lower OS resource usage), and I was wondering if I could make it so that every time I pressed "restart" from either OS I wouldn't have to change selections.
In practice this would also affect non-restart startups, so then I might have to boot twice to get the OS I was using last time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure created thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/575546/693277), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43226/108618) and [that](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubReboot); untested:

1. Boot Ubuntu.
2. Modify `/etc/default/grub` and set `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` there.
3. In the same file set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to a non-negative integer. You may even want `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` (meaning "boot immediately without displaying the menu").
4. Use `grub-set-default` to set your default entry as Ubuntu.
5. Update your GRUB config (`update-grub`).
6. Use `grub-reboot` to point GRUB to Windows on the next boot only. The code from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112284/108618) may be your starting point:

   > ```
   > grub-reboot "$(grep -i 'windows' /boot/grub/grub.cfg|cut -d"'" -f2)"
   > ```

   Verify if it works, just reboot. After you get it right, go back to Ubuntu and make the `grub-reboot` command run automatically whenever Ubuntu starts (e.g. put it in `/etc/rc.local`).

Now your machine will boot Ubuntu by default. When it boots, GRUB is told to start Windows once on the next boot. So your second boot will run Windows. The third boot should behave exactly as the first one -- and so on.

Comment: That's a pretty clever solution; I might test that some time just to see if it works. Sounds like the result I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

We can only set default boot operating system, then system chooses a default boot operating system to run automatically every time.

But if we have more than one operating system installed on our PC, the system does not know that which operating system we want to boot, if so, then we will have 30 seconds by default to choose an operating system to run before the default operating system runs automatically. For the details, we can refer:

[How to Choose a Default Operating System to Run at Startup in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21934-choose-default-operating-system-run-startup-windows-10-a.html)