# GRUB automatically alternating defaults?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

QUESTION:

On a Windows/Linux dual-boot system, is there a way to tell grub to automatically alternate between the defaults, like that every other boot go to Windows, and every other boot go to Linux?

WHY:

I have a dual-boot computer with Windows and Linux (Mint) side by side. By default grub boots to Linux with a 30 second waiting time.

I have set up remote control software (earlier TeamViewer, now I am using AnyDesk) on both OSes so that I can control the computer remotely, no matter if it is booted to Windows or Linux. The remote control software becomes active at OS login, so it is possible to boot the machine and log into it remotely.

However, naturally I can't see the grub boot menu remotely as the remote control software is not yet active at that point, so basically I cannot remotely decide to boot to the other OS, only to the default one that GRUB offers.

EDIT: It occurred to me though that I could partly achieve what I want by making Linux the default grub OS, and if I want to boot to Windows, I change the GRUB default to Windows while in Linux, before booting the machine. However, if the grub change is permanent, then I can't boot back to Linux anymore? Is there a way to make the grub default change only temporary?

I would still prefer the "automatically alternating default" as that is less manual work in case I want to switch OS remotely.

EDIT: I'll have to test at home whether this is the solution:

[Boot GRUB to entry not booted to last time?](https://superuser.com/questions/1345321/boot-grub-to-entry-not-booted-to-last-time)

Comment: Not a solution, but another approach you might not have considered - maybe you could run one OS as a VM in another instead?

Comment: No, I need (want) to run both "on the metal", due to e.g. games (yes, on both).
I do run various Linuxes also on VirtualBox otherwise though, but in this case I need a dual-boot.

Comment: I'm the author of the accepted answer to the other question; and the person who closed yours. If my answer doesn't work for you then please leave me a comment here; I will reopen your question and/or try to help.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, your suggestion in the other question is even better what I was hoping for. So now I boot into Linux by default as per those instructions, and if I want to switch to Windows through another boot, I run windows.sh in my home dir that does:
sudo grub-reboot "$(grep -i 'windows' /boot/grub/grub.cfg|cut -d"'" -f2)"
sudo shutdown -r now
And poof then I boot to Windows next time, but only one time.

Comment: @timppu Follow my answer to the end. It explicitly says: "After you get it right, go back to Ubuntu and make the `grub-reboot` command run automatically whenever Ubuntu starts (e.g. put it in `/etc/rc.local`)". Do the same or equivalent in your Mint.